# (STM32) Is it possible to capture two different signals using Timer1, CH1 and CH2 only?

Tags: input, embedded, stm32, capture, pwm

I am currently working on a project and I am trying to measure duty cycle and frequency of a two different signals connected to Timer1 (channel 1 and channel 2)
   PE9     ------> TIM1_CH1
   PE11     ------> TIM1_CH2

My plan is to switch between CH1 and CH2 at every 100ms, calling a function named PwmInput_SwitchChannels(BOOL) which contains the right configurations for every channel. In the interrupt function I want to capture the values and to store them in an array of two element of pwm_capture type.

```
typedef struct
       {
   __IO UInt16            uhIC2Value;
   __IO UInt16            uhDutyCycle;
   __IO UInt32            uwFrequency;
        }
        pwm_capture;
pwm_capture input_capture[2];
```

The problem is that the captured values for 1 channel ​​do not match the real ones and it seems to be a problem in the PwmInput_SwitchChannels.
When I independently tested both channels the code worked very well and the interrupt function was doing its job.

```
            #define PIN18_PWM_A ((BOOL)  0)
            #define PIN19_PWM_B ((BOOL)  1)

            typedef struct
                    {
               __IO UInt16            uhIC2Value;
               __IO UInt16            uhDutyCycle;
               __IO UInt32            uwFrequency;
                    }
                    pwm_capture;

             pwm_capture input_capture[2];
             BOOL Tim1_Channels = 0;
             UInt16 counter_pwm = 0;


            void HalTim_MainFunction(void)
            {
                if ( FALSE != rb_InitStatus )
                {
                    counter_pwm++;
                    if(counter_pwm % 100 == 0)
                    {
                        Tim1_Channels = ! Tim1_Channels;
                        PwmInput_SwitchChannels(Tim1_Channels);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    ;
                }
            }





            void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
            {
                if(htim->Instance == TIM1)
                {
                switch(Tim1_Channels){
                  case PIN18_PWM_A:
                  {
                    if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2)
                    {
                        /* Get the Input Capture value */
                        input_capture[0].uhIC2Value = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

                        if (input_capture[0].uhIC2Value != 0)
                        {
                            /* Duty cycle computation */
                            input_capture[0].uhDutyCycle = ((HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_1)) * 100) / input_capture[0].uhIC2Value;

                            /* uwFrequency computation
                  TIM1 counter clock = (RCC_Clocks.HCLK_Frequency)/2 */
                            input_capture[0].uwFrequency = (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()) / input_capture[0].uhIC2Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            input_capture[0].uhDutyCycle = 0;
                            input_capture[0].uwFrequency = 0;
                        }

                    }
                  break;
                  }
                  case PIN19_PWM_B:
                  {
                      if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
                      {
                          /* Get the Input Capture value */
                          input_capture[1].uhIC2Value = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

                          if (input_capture[1].uhIC2Value != 0)
                          {
                              /* Duty cycle computation */
                              input_capture[1].uhDutyCycle = ((HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_2)) * 100) / input_capture[1].uhIC2Value;

                              /* uwFrequency computation
                               TIM1 counter clock = (RCC_Clocks.HCLK_Frequency)/2 */
                              input_capture[1].uwFrequency = (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()) / input_capture[1].uhIC2Value;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              input_capture[1].uhDutyCycle = 0;
                              input_capture[1].uwFrequency = 0;
                          }

                      }
                  break;
                  }
                  default:
                          Error_Handler();

                }
              }
            }





            void PwmInput_SwitchChannels(BOOL aux)
            {
                TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig_aux = {0};
                TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig_aux = {0};
                TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigIC_aux = {0};

                /*##-4- Stop the Input Capture in interrupt mode ##########################*/
                 if (HAL_TIM_IC_Stop_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
                {
                 /* Starting Error */
                 Error_Handler();
                }

                 /*##-5- Stop the Input Capture in interrupt mode ##########################*/
                if (HAL_TIM_IC_Stop_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                {
                 /* Starting Error */
                 Error_Handler();
                }

               switch (aux){
               case PIN18_PWM_A:
               {
                        sSlaveConfig_aux.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_RESET;
                        sSlaveConfig_aux.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_TI2FP2;
                        sSlaveConfig_aux.TriggerPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
                        sSlaveConfig_aux.TriggerFilter = 0;
                        if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sSlaveConfig_aux) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                           Error_Handler();
                         }
                        sMasterConfig_aux.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
                        sMasterConfig_aux.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
                        if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig_aux) != HAL_OK)
                         {
                            Error_Handler();
                         }
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_FALLING;
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_INDIRECTTI;
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICFilter = 0;
                         if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigIC_aux, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                         {
                            Error_Handler();
                         }
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
                         if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigIC_aux, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
                         {
                            Error_Handler();
                         }
                        break;
               }
               case PIN19_PWM_B:
               {
                        sSlaveConfig_aux.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_RESET;
                        sSlaveConfig_aux.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_TI1FP1;
                        sSlaveConfig_aux.TriggerPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
                        sSlaveConfig_aux.TriggerFilter = 0;
                        if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sSlaveConfig_aux) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                           Error_Handler();
                         }
                        sMasterConfig_aux.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
                        sMasterConfig_aux.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
                        if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig_aux) != HAL_OK)
                         {
                            Error_Handler();
                         }
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_FALLING;
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_INDIRECTTI;
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICFilter = 0;
                         if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigIC_aux, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
                         {
                            Error_Handler();
                         }
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
                         sConfigIC_aux.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
                         if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigIC_aux, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                         {
                            Error_Handler();
                         }
                        break;
                }
                default:
                      Error_Handler();

                 /*##-4- Start the Input Capture in interrupt mode ##########################*/
                if (HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
                {
                  /* Starting Error */
                  Error_Handler();
                }

                 /*##-5- Start the Input Capture in interrupt mode ##########################*/
                if (HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                {
                  /* Starting Error */
                  Error_Handler();
                }
            }
            }
```

My intention is to switch correctly between the two channels (only using Tim1_CH1 and Tim1_CH2, due to the hardware limitations) without affect the results and the performance.

Comment: What is the expected frequency range? Which STM32 MCU do you have? What is the clock frequency?

Comment: Hi, both signals have a range between 10khz to 50khz, the clock frequency is 48Mhz, with no prescaler for timer1, and I use stm32f103vct6.

Comment: TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigIC = {0};

  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause is that `Tim1_Channels` is not declared `volatile`. It is written to in the main function, and accessed in the interrupt handler. Lacking the `volatile` qualifier, nothing prevents the optimizer to hold the value in a register, and never write it back to memory. As far as the optimizer knows, the interrupt handler where the value is accessesd, is never called from the main program.

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved the problem by modifying interrupt function and I declared Tim1_Channels volatile, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by declaring the following variables as volatile and also by modifying the code inside interrupt function

```
 __IO pwm_capture input_capture[2] = {{0}, {0}};
 __IO BOOL Tim1_Channels = 0;
 __IO UInt16 counter_pwm = 0;


 void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
 {
    if(htim->Instance == TIM1)
     {
    switch(Tim1_Channels){
    case PIN18_PWM_A:
     {
    if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2)
    {
        /* Get the Input Capture value */
        input_capture[0].uhIC2Value = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

        if (input_capture[0].uhIC2Value != 0)
        {
            /* Duty cycle computation */
            input_capture[0].uhDutyCycle = ((HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_2)) * 100) / input_capture[0].uhIC2Value;

            /* uwFrequency computation
  TIM1 counter clock = (RCC_Clocks.HCLK_Frequency)/2 */
            input_capture[0].uwFrequency = (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()) / input_capture[0].uhIC2Value;
        }
        else
        {
            input_capture[0].uhDutyCycle = 0;
            input_capture[0].uwFrequency = 0;
        }

    }
     break;
  }
  case PIN19_PWM_B:
  {
      if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
      {
          /* Get the Input Capture value */
          input_capture[1].uhIC2Value = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

          if (input_capture[1].uhIC2Value != 0)
          {
              /* Duty cycle computation */
              input_capture[1].uhDutyCycle = ((HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_2)) * 100) / input_capture[1].uhIC2Value;

              /* uwFrequency computation
    TIM1 counter clock = (RCC_Clocks.HCLK_Frequency)/2 */
              input_capture[1].uwFrequency = (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()) / input_capture[1].uhIC2Value;
          }
          else
          {
              input_capture[1].uhDutyCycle = 0;
              input_capture[1].uwFrequency = 0;
          }

      }
      break;
    }
  default:
      Error_Handler();

   }
  }
```

}